# Search function symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony-3.2

Hello everyone I am new with `Symfony3` and I have a problem with a `DQL` request it return an empty result!
The request must return all the Logements with specific fields from the SearchBar!

LogementController:

```
public function searchAction(request $request)
{

    $log = $request->request->get('browser'); 
    $cat = $request->request->get('checkbox_type_1');
    $vil = $request->request->get('location[]');


    $q =  $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->getRepository('AcmeImmoBundle:Logement')
        ->createQueryBuilder('A');

    $q  ->leftJoin('A.categorie', 'C')
        ->addselect('C')


        ->leftJoin('A.district', 'D')
        ->addselect('D')    
        ->leftJoin('D.ville', 'V')
        ->addselect('V')
        ->where($q->expr()->eq('A.logementname', ':log')) 
        ->andWhere($q->expr()->eq('C.categorietype', ':cat'))

        ->andWhere($q->expr()->eq('V.villename', ':vil')) 
        ->setParameters(array('log' => $log,'cat' => $cat,'vil' => $vil));

$logement =   $q->getQuery()->getResult();
          return $this->render('logement/search.html.twig', array(
                               'logements' => $logement));
}
```

Comment: If u want more informations just ask for it , thanks for helpin me !

Answer (score 0):

It actually hart to understand the problem without structure. Some dummy part of data would be helpful.

Also you can try to run

```
$q->getQuery()->getSQL()
```

It and check generated sql query.

And one more thing. Please do not build queries in controller it always makes code hard to read. You can define Custom repository class for example and define a method there that will assemble query builder

Comment: Павел МатвиенкоПавел Матвиенко thank u i ll try to define the querybuilder in a repository , what should i post for more understandin  (entity , twig, repository ) !!